# How to draw two list of items side by side

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to draw some list of items and print them to a file in this format

```
 items   amount

 maize   $50
 meat    $100
```

i have tried using stringbulder

```
private List<sting> _Items;
private List<string> _Uprices;

//list of items
StringBuilder myItems = StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in _Items) {
    myItems.AppendLine(item.PadRight (30));
}

//list of prices
StringBulder prices = StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in _Uprices) {
    prices.AppendLine(item.PadRight (30));
}
```

then

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics();
g.DrawString(myItems,new Font("Times New Roman",12),new SolidBrush(Color.Black),20,20);
```

but the output i get here is terrible
if i add the foreach items to a string, the last value gets printed.
please can some one help me out on this?

what am i doing wrong please, i have search around google, could not find an answer.

update:

please check this code snippet 
[here](https://gist.github.com/rexeze/93669180edc2133f53a43cbbbd731ae4)

i think the question is not well understood. but i have updated it with a link to the source code, printing to OneNote.

Comment: Printing them to a file and printing them to a graphic are two different things.

Comment: Do you want to file or screen?

Comment: You can create array of strings and then print them in a foreach loop with `g.DrawString` method one by one.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as such; but if there is a correlation between the item and the price, the best way would be to store the two properties together in some kind of structure or class; and then you can override .ToString()

Comment: To print or display __columns__ you often will need to use a __fixed size font__ like Courier or Consolas. Other than that __you  need to clarify your actual goal.__ The answers are widely differing in a ludicrous way because __nobody seems to understand your question!__

Comment: i think you a right @TaW, i have updated the question with a gist with the complete code. i want to print to oneNote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear because you say you want to write to file but use `Graphics`.

Assuming output is to file:
Using Linq's `Zip` and C# 6.0's String Interpolation you can do it like this:

```
List<string> _Items = new List<string> { "maize", "meat" };
List<string> _Uprices = new List<string> { "$50", "$100" };

// For prior c# 6 use here string.Format
var lines = _Items.Zip(_Uprices, (item, price) => $"{item}  {price}").ToList();

using (var stream = File.CreateText(@"C:\myfile.txt"))
{
    stream.WriteLine("Items - Amount");
    lines.ForEach(stream.WriteLine);
}

//Output:

// maize  $50
// meat   $100
```

For OneNote output replae the `using` above with:

```
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    g.DrawString(line,new Font("Times New Roman",12),new SolidBrush(Color.Black),20,20);
}
```

*I still would recommend to use some other structure for the data, like a class with 2 properties, than 2 lists that correlate by index*

Comment: i will try using the class with properties, and get back to you

Comment: @EzeSundayEze - I saw your update and that you want to print to OneNote. Basically replace the code of the `using` with what you need but the main issue is formatting the rows - which is the `.Zip` :)

Comment: @EzeSundayEze - I'm not sure I understand. Each item in `lines` is the string you want. Put that in `g.DrawString(line,new Font("Times New Roman",12),new SolidBrush(Color.Black),20,20);`

Comment: Thanks, i will take this as my answer. I will fix up the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print to a file you need to use File and Text Writer.

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
    File.Create(path);

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
tw.WriteLine("items ammount");
tw.Close();
```

In order to generate the 2 things side by side this is a way.

```
if (_Items.Count == _Uprices.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _Items.Count; i++)
    {
        tw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",_Items[i],_Uprices[i]));
    }
}
```

I am not going to give the complete script. Mix and match to understand it better.

Comment: am not trying to write to file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a little more information, but I think you want to create your string with a single for loop.

```
private List<sting> _Items;
private List<string> _Uprices;

StringBuilder myItems = StringBuilder();
foreach (var i = 0; i < _Items.Count; i++) {
    myItems.AppendLine(_Items[i].PadRight(30) + _Uprices[i]);
}

Console.Write(myItems);
```

Comment: i have used this code snippet, but output overlaps with other content. @styfle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a dictionnary ?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use a Dictionary and just print key with value?

and then try this

```
int y=20;
    foreach(var keyValuePair in dictionary) {
     g.DrawString(keyValuePair.Key+"\t"+keyValuePair.Value, new Font("Times New Roman",12, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),20,y+=15);
    }
```

Comment: It may occure that items of `_Items` are not *unique*; if they are `Dictionary<String, String>` is a soution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *Linq*, `Zip` to be exact:

To draw all the lines combined:

```
string myItems = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _Items
  .Zip(_Uprices, (item, price) => $"{item}  {price}"));

g.DrawString(myItems, ...);
```

If you want to put the lines down to the *file*:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", _Items
  .Zip(_Uprices, (item, price) => $"{item}  {price}"));
```

Finally, you can *materialize* the outcome (say, as array) and either draw it or write to the file:

```
string[] result = _Items
  .Zip(_Uprices, (item, price) => $"{item}  {price}")
  .ToArray();

...

// draw all the lines in one go 
g.DrawString(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result) ...); 

...
// draw line after line (in case you have other lines/text to output)
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i) {
  g.DrawString(result[i], ...);
  ... 
}  

...

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", result);
```

Comment: this works, but overlaps with other contents, i have updated, the question with a url to the source code